# Can a gen3 SATA harddrive be forced to always link at gen2 speed?

Tags: windows, sata

Is there a PC tool to program a gen3 SATA harddrive to avoid a link attempt at the gen3 speed (6Gb) and always start the link negotiation at the gen2 speed (3Gb)?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this may be possible via jumper. What are the specific drives (make/model) and controllers involved?

Checking the documentation for the drives will show you the options available. I've done this in cases where 1.5Gbps SATA disks did not negotiate properly.